# I'm using a biscuit joiner and my butt joints are about 1/16 off. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: carpentry, shelving, joinery

I feel like I'm using the joiner right -- making, say, an inverted U, I:

- set up my reference marks on both pieces so they match
- clamping the sides to my work bench and aligning the biscuit joiner base with the top edge of the sides, cut into the sides to make the biscuit slot (I am pushing down at this point)
- clamping the top piece, with the bottom of the shelf facing down, push the biscuit joiner directly into the ends of the sides according to the reference marks (I am pushing in from the side to make these cuts)

When I join the pieces, the biscuits fit well, but the side pieces are about 1/16" higher than the shelf between the two.

I am using 5/8" plywood in this case, and a Dewalt biscuit joiner. I'm aware that the joiner is made to hit the middle of 3/4" ply, but I don't know why that should make a difference.

Comment: Maybe the different way you push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method of doing the sides sounds rife with potential to tip the tool and throw the registration of the fence off. The ergonomics are all set up for the cuts to be "pushing in from the side" with the registration fence of the tool resting on top in both cases. Standing the tool up and pushing down means gravity is no longer holding the registration fence on the top surface.

So if you want to "make an inverted U" clamp the ends of the U so the top (end, or edge, depending on the U in question) is on top, set the fence on it, and push into the face of the board. For the center of the U, I believe you are already doing the normal thing  top  face on top, pushing into the end or edge of the U with the fence registered on top. You might need to clamp some additional scrap to the back of the side pieces to have sufficient surface for the fence to be stable on - or you can clamp it to the edge of your bench, with its top level with the bench top, if that fits.